# Cannot install burg: error during installation

Tags: burg, mbr, grub2

I tried to install burg and I got an error.

I've used the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install
sudo apt-get install burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
```

Until here everything went fine, but after the following command I get the error:

```
aneal@ubuntu:~$ sudo burg-install /dev/sda3 && sudo update-burg
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
/usr/sbin/burg-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a partition instead of the MBR.  This is a BAD idea..
/usr/sbin/burg-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/burg-setup: error: if you really want blocklists, use --force.
```

[image: i suppose sda3 is the relative drive to install brug in MBR]

Now I think I cannot restart. I suppose if I boot I will get grub rescue, and I know how to get over that, my problem is how to install burg into the MBR now.

EDIT:

```
aneal@ubuntu:~$ sudo burg-install /dev/sda && sudo update-burg
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Installation finished. No error reported.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Generating burg.cfg ...
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
burg-probe: error: /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk is not a block device.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
error: cannot seek `/dev/sda'.
done
```

And same is the result with sda2 .

fdisk -l Result :

```
aneal@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x97646c29

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1531    12290016+  42  SFS
/dev/sda2   *        1531        1543      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3            1543       14070   100618240   42  SFS
/dev/sda4           14070       38914   199559512   42  SFS

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3965 MB, 3965190144 bytes
49 heads, 48 sectors/track, 3292 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2352 * 512 = 1204224 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *           4        3293     3868160    b  W95 FAT32
```

Comment: I suspect Burg does not support the SFS file system you have chosen to use

Answer (score 1):

The command to install Burg should be `sudo burg-install /dev/sda && sudo update-burg`

You should consider installing Burg Manager - [details on installation can be found here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Burg-manager?content=127497) - it is a GUI interface to aid in the configuration and setup of Burg.